# Django allauth REST social login without DRF

Tags: django, react-native, rest, django-allauth

I've been searching quite a while for a solution to integrate social logins provided by Django allauth with a mobile app, but all seem to point towards using DRF.

My Django project doesn't have DRF and I'd rather avoid to integrate it, as there are many things that would need to be changed in a rather complex project.

Is there any solution to integrate Allauth's social logins via REST in a non-DRF project, or will I have to re-write allauth's views to REST by hand?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use django rest-auth that's make the process easy there is no need to make any serializer
Here is the documentation and installation link for django rest-auth
https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

I hope my answer help you

Comment: It would be more helpful, if you could sketch a solution here and refer to the docs only for extended reference.

Comment: I've checked django-rest-auth, but it depends on DRF, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Anyway, I've started to deconstruct django-rest-auth to try to make it work as standalone, without dependencies on DRF.